# Uvwrap Issue : Pink line appear

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to uvwraping a hair mesh that I made, but it looks like I made something wrong.
I'm making a gradient color with my hair but I see pink things on, I've already changed the size of the texture (1000 x 1000 to 5000 x 5000) but nothing changed, I still see that pink lines :

***This is what im trying to do :***
[image: Looks a simple gradient BUT]

***This is what i get when I zoom on the mesh :***
[image: bad]

Is anybody can help me on that ? Thanks

Comment: Oh and, I'm using blender 2.79b !

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok I'll do that !

Comment: No one know how to fix that ? :/

Comment: Please show your unwrap and wires if possible so we can better see what is going on.